# How to save the log info with "nosetests --with-xunit"?

Tags: python, logging, python-unittest

This is my simple test case:

```
import unittest
import logging

class TestAdd(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S',
                            level=logging.INFO)

    def test_add(self):
        logging.info("Begin testing")
        self.assertEqual(1+1, 2, 'Failed to verify the add function.')
        logging.info("End testing")
```

If I run the test with following cmd, then I can get the log info.

```
    # nosetests test_add.py --nologcapture 
    2015-08-20 05:34:09 INFO Begin testing
    2015-08-20 05:34:09 INFO End testing

    .
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 1 test in 0.001s

    OK
```

But I really want to use save these info to .xml file, so I use `# nosetests test_add.py --with-xunit` to generate a file named `nosetests.xml`. The file only tell me that I pass the test and no other info. How can I write these logging info to the `nosetests.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ nosetests --verbosity=3 -x --with-xunit
```

Also use the nose.tools collection rather than 'import unittest'.
The basic test suite could be something like:

```
import code  
import operator

m = code.Math()

def test_sum():  
    """Check is sum method is equivalent to operator"""
    eq_(m.sum(1, 1), operator.add(1, 1))
```

Here is a good article
http://www.metaklass.org/nose-making-your-python-tests-smell-better/